# background image not repeating for dynamically added content

Tags: css

We have one small chat in site where some background image is there in chat
it looks cool but when customer clicks on order status it asks for order no but when this content is added background image disappears

we tried several thread in stackoverflow but nothing is working

we tried adding these things

```
background-size: cover;
    /* background-size: 100% 100%; */
    background-repeat: repeat;
```

when we increase the height to 1000% it works and shows image but then our scrollTop goes to wrong place

here is our code and
class of interest
pushdaddy-body pushy-whatsapp-body

```
.pushy-whatsapp-body:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: .08;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/whatsapp99.png?v=1623221870);
```

here is live site where you can test
https://itsneotpras.myshopify.com/

click on chat and just click on order status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an absolute `:before` with height 100%, because 100% is relative to the parent height.

Instead here's three solutions:

#### 1. New common parent element

Create another simple **DIV wrapper** with `min-height: 100%` that will be the **new parent of your message**s.  That way, the min-height will be relative to the parent, but as soon you'll have more messages - it will grow as the content grows.  Also ***don't*** make it position absolute.

- PS:  The background will move with the scroll!

#### 2. Make it sticky

Add to your :before pseudo:

```css
  content: "";
  position: sticky;   /* instead of absolute */
```

- PS: The background will **not** move with the scroll!

#### 3. Parent background

Another way, if you want your background to be "fixed", change the background opacity in an image editor, and assign it to the `.pushy-whatsapp-body` element.

- PS: The background will **not** move with the scroll!

Comment: adding sticky adds blank space before and overall it is not covering total area. it keeps some blank space at top which is without image and in bottom it takes whole chat to next page of sort means when sticky is given and we click on chat nothing shows in chatbox when we scroll it is visible in second page

Comment: @sonutup that's caused from the missing `z-index`. You should play around it. Or add a higher z-index to every positioned child element.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As your box scrolls, your ::before element moves with it. I would take it off the ::before element and add it to the actual element's background, or modify how your ::before stays in place.

Comment: I should say, the other answers are correct, I just feel like you need a picture to maybe understand where it's going. You could probably set the absolute bottom to 0 and it would stretch down into place, and remove the height requirement. Let the browser calculate how tall  it is, rather than telling it.

Answer (score -1):

Can you just take it off the pseudo element? Put your `background-image` on the div class.

`<div class="pushdaddy-body pushy-whatsapp-body"></div>`

`background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/whatsapp99.png?v=1623221870");`

Comment: oh was it? Sorry!